# n-th primitive root of unity and minimal polinomials over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I know there are questions talking about similar issues here, but I don't understand a step that in the answers seem obvious steps.

Given a finite field $F_q$,

when I have a primitive n-th root of unity $\eta$ over $F_q$, I know that $\eta \in F_{q^d}$ (where $d = O_n(q)$).   ($*$)

If $P(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\eta$ in $F_q[x]$, is $\eta \in F_q[x]/P(X)$?

I'm trying to understand why $(*)$ implies that the minimal polynomial of $\eta$ in $F_q[x]$ has degree $d$.

Comment: I forgot to say that gcd(n,q) = 1.

Comment: By Galois theory of finite fields the zeros of $P(x)$ are $\eta,\eta^q,\eta^{q^2},\eta^{q^3},\ldots$. They start repeating at the point where $q^\ell\equiv1\pmod n$. This happens exactly when $\ell=d$, implying that
$$P(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(x-\eta^{q^k})$$ is stable under the Frobenius, and hence has coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_q$.